# Binding a .sh file (shell script) to a set of keys

Tags: linux, shell-script, keyboard-shortcuts

I have wrote some commands in a shell script to run some ROS commands to launch my robot. I recently got a control pad where I can bind certain buttons to some keybinds like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> etc...
I want to be able to bind my shell script to a key bind as well, so that I can launch my robot with the push of a button.

I added a shortcut to the keyboard settings on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. For the command section I put: `~/shell_scripts/robot_launch.sh` The same command I run in my terminal to run the sh file. However, the shortcut does not work.

Is it possible to bind a key to a shell script?

Comment: Welcome, are you using Ubuntu with Gnome?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. In Gnome (and I believe other DE's as well) you have to use the full path of the script when asked:

```
/full/path/of/script
```

`~` is not expanded to your home directory, so the script can't be found

Comment: I am using Gnome. I went to settings > devices > keyboard > keyboard shortcuts and added a custom shortcut. I added the following as the command: "/home/nuc/shell_scripts/test.sh" and binded it to ctrl + 1, however it still does not work.
test.sh is a shell script i wrote that just runs "pwd"

my actual robot_launch.sh runs a bunch of roslaunch commands. The terminal output is not necessary. However, when I press run "ps" it shows that there is no roslaunch running in the background.

Comment: @user528125 You have to make the script executable: `chmod +x script`. Though depending on what the script does the problem could be elsewhere.

Comment: I have done that. The shell script runs perfectly when I run it in the terminal. If I change the script to one line: firefox "google.com" the script can be binded to a key. It looks like gnome keybinds allow me to launch apps. Even through shell scripts. Is it possible for me to run a sequence of commands in the terminal through a gnome keybind? My original idea was to write a shell script which runs a sequence of commands. And that shell script works perfectly, if i run it in the terminal. But it does not work when binded to a key.

Comment: The issue has been resolved, the "~" was half the problem. The other half was that the script would need to be ran in a terminal. So a new script was created which launched a terminal and then ran my original script in it. That new script was then binded to my controller